# Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'

Tags: python, numpy

Example of data that I want to replace
[image]

Data has the following attributes

1. Buying v-high,high,med,low
2. Maint v-high,high,med,low
3. Doors 2,3,4,5-more
4. persons 2,4-more
5. lug_boot small,med,big
6. safety low,med.high

here is what I did

```
enter code here
#Buying price generalization 
df["Buying_Price"]=df["Buying_Price"].replace({"vhigh":4})
df["Buying_Price"]=df["Buying_Price"].replace({"high":3})
df["Buying_Price"]=df["Buying_Price"].replace({"med":2})
df["Buying_Price"]=df["Buying_Price"].replace({"low":1})

#Maintanace generalization 
df["Maintanance_price"]=df["Maintanance_price"].replace({"vhigh":4}) 
df["Maintanance_price"]=df["Maintanance_price"].replace({"high":3})   
df["Maintanance_price"]=df["Maintanance_price"].replace({"med":2})
df["Maintanance_price"]=df["Maintanance_price"].replace({"low":1})

#lug_boot generalization 
df["Lug_boot"]=df["Lug_boot"].replace({"small":1})
df["Lug_boot"]=df["Lug_boot"].replace({"med":2})
df["Lug_boot"]=df["Lug_boot"].replace({"big":3})

#Safety Generalization 
df["Safety"]=df["Safety"].replace({"low":1})
df["Safety"]=df["Safety"].replace({"med":2})
df["Safety"]=df["Safety"].replace({"big":3})

print(df.head())
```

while printing it showed:

```
Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'
```

Comment: `df.head` doesn't do any *computations* on your data. Are you sure your error isn't some other line? Please provide **full traceback**.

Comment: Echo jpp's comment. Also you can considerably tidy your code by doing your replaces all at once using a dictionary: `replace_all_these = {'low' : 1, 'med' : 2, 'high' : 3, 'vhigh' : 4 }; df['col'] = df['col'].replace(replace_all_these)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some of you `string` you passed to replace with an (`int`)value, actually is an `ndarray` of `int64` values.
You only have `int64( here actually ndarray(dtype=int64))` type data in this column. 
See document [pandas.Dataframe.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html). 
`replace()` try to seek and compare them with the `str` values you passed.

```
df["Buying_Price"]=df["Buying_Price"].replace({"vhigh":4})
```

find all `"vhigh"` value and compare with the value currently contains, the replace it with `4`.
At the comparing it fails as try to compare `str` data with `int64 ('ndarray(dtype=int64)')`

**A brief example to simulate this:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1])
df = pd.DataFrame({"Maintanance_price": a})
df["Maintanance_price"] = df["Maintanance_price"].replace({"a":1})

print(df)
```

**Out:**

```
TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'
```

Comment: found my problem, my code works fine and Thanks for the brief explanation .. The dataset has a space after 'Safety ' that was causing the problem

Comment: This seems fixed in python 3.8 but still a problem in python 3.6

Answer (score 4):

I was facing the same issue and what worked for me was converting the datatype of the feature to an object type.

```
   train['Some_feature']=train.Some_feature.astype(object)
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code:

```
df['Maintanance_price'].replace(to_replace = ['low', 'med','high','vhigh'], value =[1,2,3,4], inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Also, as suggested by [@ouiemboughrra](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61552454/2123530), check if the values have already been converted to numeric, in case you have rerun the cell.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post as I just encountered the same issue.
I was trying to map values in **lug_boot** column from strings 'small','med' and 'big' to integers 1, 2, and 3.

Here is how I read the data from the url and stored it in a dataframe. Please note that the file format in the url is csv. Also, I used a function to extract the first row of the dataset and pass it to the 'names' parameter as column headers.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data',
             header=None,
             names=[list of column names])
```

When I checked the data and a subset of it, I realized some of the columns contain **NaN**. NaN is considered a **floating-point** value. So, I realized the part of that says ndarray(dtype=float64) may refer to these NaN values.

My solution was tweaking my read_csv and I added 'dtype=str' as the last argument.
This is the updated version:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/car/car.data',
             header=None,
             names=[list of column names], dtype = str)
```

Then I ran my mapping function and it worked.
Here is the code that wasn't working initially, but worked after adding dtype = str to my read_csv function.

```
mapping = {'small': 1, 'med':2, 'big': 3}
df.replace({'lug_boot': mapping})
```

Please note that importing everything as string in your data type may not always work. You may want to seek other solutions. For example, you may want to deal with NaN or missing values first.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue and none of the answers (so far) worked for me - the solution I found was to convert the column to '**str**' *not* type '**object**'.

```
df['col'] = df['col'].astype('str')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove whitespaces from both sides then do the replace

```
 #remove white space at both ends:
#'buying', 'maint','doors','persons','lug_boot','safety','class'
df.buying=df.buying.astype(str).str.strip()
df.maint=df.maint.astype(str).str.strip()
df.persons=df.persons.astype(str).str.strip()
df.lug_boot=df.lug_boot.astype(str).str.strip()
df.safety=df.safety.astype(str).str.strip()
df.class_account=df.class_account.astype(str).str.strip()
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason for this error is because of the number of times you execute the cell. The first time you execute the cell the transformation happens. At this point if you try to rerun the same cell, the data type for physicalEvidence and contact is now an int rather than a string. So when the replace method runs, it is look for a sting, but DOES NOT find any because all of the values have been replaced with integers.

If this happens, you'll just need to reload the dataframe (df) again and rerun the cell one time.