# encoding do not running in the fucntion, but could run independently

Tags: python, machine-learning, encoding

I am working on the [dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/competitions/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data), there are a number of categorical features, which I want to encode in top categories, while the bottom to be replaced with other in combination. As there is large number of features with different threshold values. I defined a function like this

```
def enc(threshold , features):

    for i in features:

        j = i + "other"
    
        repl = train[features].value_counts()[train[features].value_counts() <= threshold].index
        sample = pd.get_dummies(train[features].replace(repl , j))
    
        train.drop(features , axis = 1 , inplace = True)
    
        n_data = pd.concat([sample , train] , axis = 1 , join = "inner")
    
    return n_data
```

It gives the error `Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=object)' and 'tuple'` on the line `sample = ...`
Here threshold is some threshold value for top categories, and features is the list of features I want to iterate over.
When I try to run this code out of the function, it still gives me error.
But the catch is when I try just the major 2 lines out of for loop which are

```
repl = train["LandContour"].value_counts()[train["LandContour"].value_counts() <= 1000].index
a = pd.get_dummies(train["LandContour"].replace(repl , "LandContou_other"))
```

with dedicated values, it runs perfectly as I want.
I have also tried my level best of debugging and still was not able to rectify the error.
DataType of `repl` is `<class 'pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'>`
I have also looked upon a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53478932/cannot-compare-types-ndarraydtype-int64-and-str) but it didn't solved my problem
I think there is some problem in the for iteration only, or the `repl` is causing some problem

Comment: The error `DataType of repl is <class 'pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex'>` means that the repl variable is an index, that is a number that tells you where to find the item in dataframe, and the replace method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html does not accept indices are input. You must either use another method or convert from indices to something else

Comment: But then why, it works perfectly out of the for loop/function ?